# i'm not able to take a screenshot

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, error-handling, casting

```
//THIS IS MY TEST CASE
[Test]
public void SuccessfullyRegistredUser()
{
//Act
_homePage.SuccessfullyNavigateToRegistrationForm(_homePageModel);
_registrationPage.FillForm(_registrationModel);
//Assert
_registrationPage.ComfirmThatRegistrationWasSuccessfully("M CREDIT SLIPS");
}

//THIS IS MY TEAR DOWN WITH IF ELSE CONSTRUCTION IN CASE MY TEST FAIL 
[TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{
if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome != ResultState.Success)
{
Screenshot screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)Driver).GetScreenshot();  
screenshot.SaveAsFile(@"C:\test.png", ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
}
Driver.Quit();
}
 //THIS IS MY CASTING ERROR
TearDown : System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 
'RegistrationForm.Decoratos.WebDriver' to type 'OpenQA.Selenium.ITakesScreenshot'.
```

I intentionally did my test to fail. So in the end I do this check if the test fails I want to take a screenshot, but it doesn't happen and it gives me this error, about casting. How I can fix it.

Comment: What is `RegistrationForm.Decoratos.WebDriver`?

Answer (score -1):

```
    if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome != ResultState.Success)
{
Screenshot screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)Driver).GetScreenshot();  
screenshot.SaveAsFile(@"C:\test.png", ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
}

Used this code 
    FILE file = ((TakesScreenshot)Driver).getScreenshot(Output.FILE);  
FileUtils.copyfile(file,new File("path to save image file");
```

Comment: You need use File(IO) in selenium to take screenshot and you can store that image file into your project path

Comment: Did i should instal something xtra nuggets or something, because doesn't present current option (copyFile) and also doesn't allowed me to do this new (new File), and this also (Output.FILE) this (FILE) doesnt exist

Comment: Are you doing maven with TestNg ?

Comment: No, I using Selenium WebDriver with C#